# Ampleness of the normal bundle to the Albanese image

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, abelian-varieties

Let $X$ be a projective surface of general type over $\mathbb{C}$, and assume that $\Omega_X$ is globally generated. Then the Albanese map $a \colon X \to \operatorname{Alb}(X)$ is a local embedding <s>namely, a finite, étale cover</s> with image $a(X) \subset \operatorname{Alb}(X)$. It is also well known that $a(X)$ generate $\operatorname{Alb}(X)$.

> **Question.** Is the normal bundle of $a(X)$ an ample vector bundle?

By a result of Hartshorne (see [1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/187149/on-a-proposition-in-hartshornes-paper-ample-vector-bundles-on-curves)), in order to have a positive answer, it suffices to check that every curve in $a(X)$ generates $\operatorname{Alb}(X)$, see also MO187149 [On a proposition in Hartshorne's paper "Ample vector bundles on curves"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/187149/on-a-proposition-in-hartshornes-paper-ample-vector-bundles-on-curves). In particular, this shows that the answer to the previous question is "yes" when $\operatorname{Alb}(X)$ is *simple*. But what can happen in general?

**References.**

[1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/187149/on-a-proposition-in-hartshornes-paper-ample-vector-bundles-on-curves). *Hartshorne, R.*, [**Ample vector bundles on curves**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0027763000014379), Nagoya Math. J. 43, 73-89 (1971). [ZBL0218.14018](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0218.14018).

Comment: I think that fails when $X$ is a product of two hyperbolic curves.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Could you please give more details?

Comment: If $X$ equals a product $C\times D$, then the Albanese morphism for $X$ is the product of the Albanese morphisms of the factors, $\text{alb}_C\times\text{alb}_D:C\times D \to \text{Alb}(C)\times \text{Alb}(D)$.  Thus, the pullback of the tangent bundle by the Albanese morphism is the direct sum, $\text{pr}_C^*\text{alb}_C^*T_{\text{Alb}(C)}\oplus \text{pr}_C^*\text{alb}_D^*T_{\text{Alb}(D)}$.  Therefore the normal bundle is also a direct sum $\text{pr}_C^* N_{\text{Alb}(C)/C}\oplus \text{pr}_D^*N_{\text{Alb}(D)/D}$.  These are not ample on curves in fibers of $\text{pr}_C,\text{pr}_D$.

Comment: "The Albanese map is a finite, étale cover onto its image": not necessarily. You only know that it is unramified, the image could very well be singular.

Comment: @abx: ok, thanks. In fact, I only know that the differential of the Albanese map is everywhere of maximal rank. Do you know any example of surface such that $\Omega_X$ is globally generated and $a(X)$ is singular?